# Online resources for medieval Persian chess games or problems?

Tags: chess-variants, history, problems

I am looking for any collection of chess games of [al-Suli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Bakr_bin_Yahya_al-Suli#Chess) or anyone medieval scholar's composition of games. Any resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at   [this](http://www.chess.com/forum/view/game-showcase/the-oldest-chess-game-recorded)  page.
I hope it helps..

Comment: While it is a great example of the particular game, I was actually looking forward to a whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not yet in the public domain, H.J. Murray's *A History of Chess* can be found on Google Books, and contains a large number of constructed shatranj problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have found quite a few websites I popped the phrase for "Shatranj chess problem" into a search. The rules are, as always, on [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatranj#Player_classification) Bishops represent alfils, and queens for ferz, in the following diagrams.

On chessvariants.com, there is an excellent resource page entitled ["Chess Problems Of 1001 Years Ago."](https://www.chessvariants.com/mansubat.dir/mansindex.html) Here is the longest problem. This can be played out as the alfils and ferz are still.

```
[Title "The Water Wheel, Al-Suli, 930, Mate In 36"]
[FEN "rQ2nbbR/P5p1/pkp1pn2/1Pr2B2/2Pq2Pp/PN1P4/1N3p2/1KB3R1 w K - 0 1"]

1. Na4!+ Kb7 2. Na5+ Kc8 3. Nb6+ Kd8 4. Nb7+ Ke7 5. Nc8+ Kf7 6. Nd8+ Kg6 7. Ne7+ Kg5 8. Nf7+ Kf4 9. Ng6+ Kf3 10. Ng5+ Ke2 11. Nf4+ Kd2 12. Nf3+ Kc3 13. Ne2+ Kb3 14. Nfxd4+ Ka4 15. Nc3+ Ka5 16. Nb3+ Kb6 17. Na4+ Kb7 18. Nbxc5+ Kc8 19. Nb6 Kd8 20. Nb7+ Ke7 21. Nc8+ Kf7 22. Nd8+ Kg6 23. Ne7+ Kg5 24. Nf7+ Kf4 25. Ng6+ Kf3 26. Ng5+  Ke2 27. Nf4+ Kd2 28. Nf3+ Kc3 29. Ne2+ Kb3 30. Nd2+ Ka4 30. Nc3+ Ka5 31. Nc3+ Ka5 32. Nb3+ Kb6 33. Na4+ Kb7 34. Na5+ Kc8 35. Nb6+ Kd8 36. Nxc6#
```

In addition, I remembered a particular problem on Tim Krabbe's site in [Journal Entry #146.](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary_8.htm) The source is "100 Classics of the Chessboard" by Dickins and Ebert.

```
[Title "MS. 791 Casanatense Library, Rome, 15th Century, Mate In 6"]
[FEN "4k3/4P3/4P3/4P3/4P3/4P3/4P2B/R1N1K3 w Q - 0 1"]

1. Nb3! Kxe7 2. Ra8 Kxe6 3. Ra7 Kxe5 4. Ra6 Kxe45. Ra5 Kxe3 6. Re5#
```

Lastly, the Wikipedia page for Shatranj gives this classic.

```
[Title "Dilaram Problem, c. 10th century, Mate In 5"]
[FEN "1r4k1/8/5PP1/8/K1n3NR/7B/1r6/7R w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Solution: 1. Rh8+! Kxh8 2. Af5+ (the alfil leaps over the knight) Kg8 3. Rh8+ Kxh8 4. g7+ Kg8 5. Nh6#